# Count current streak in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to count how many continuous days user has used the app.

It updates the label depending on the streaks and if user has not used the app for a day the number goes back to zero.

How can I achieve this? I have searched but could not find any source.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### For this you have a few things to take into consideration:

---

### When to report last usage?

- **Your app idea may include the need to perform some actions before
  considering a complete usage.** For example, after loading or presenting something on the screen, after retrieving data and performing some actions, etc.
- **Just by intention of opening the app.** The only intention is for the user to hit your app´s icon to launch the app, nevermind if he set it to a close state before even passing your loading screen.

> This can be a bit unpredictable

- **When sending the app to background**.

> Important to notice that iOS can kill your process anytime after your
>   app is sent to background, so better to do it right after user´s
>   action.

Also, the user could not open your app again in a while.

You can subscribe to background capabilities for letting your app be active for a while longer while transitioning to suspended/close state if you are going to save data out of the iPhone.

The function you are looking for is [`applicationDidEnterBackground(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622997-applicationdidenterbackground)

> **Strong Points of this approach**
>
> You get last time that your app was **actually** used.

For more on the application life cycle and how to handle it correctly, please visit [apple documentation about this topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions/StrategiesforHandlingAppStateTransitions.html)

### Do I need this information to be available between installs & Where to save ?

---

- If you care about this counter to be stable and remains intact between installs you can not save it in any local database or `NSUserDefaults`. In this case you should implement some kind of online storage, via user creation & handling in your servers or the use of **iCloud** alternatives.
- If your information is sensitive (let's say that you are going to give some **money like reward** to your user for opening your app **1000** times) then you can not store it in `NSUserDefaults`, as it is not encripted and can be modified.

### What to save in order to count days in a row?

---

Simplicity is king when dealing with stored data and there are many ways to achieve this specific task.

I would go with:

- Storing the first date (*ignoring time if you are dealing with calendar days, but including it if you are handling 24hours lapses as your day instead*)
- Storing last visit date (*same considerations apply*).

> You could save complete timestamp in order to be able of change your mind later ;-)

In my app I would do the maths then with current date data (`now = NSDate()`) before making any changes.

1. If timelapse between `now` and `last visit date` is **bigger** than
   a "*Day*", then update `first visit date` with `now`.
2. Save `now` data into `last visit date` storage.

> Your counter will always be the difference in "*Days*" between `now` and `first visit date`.

### Summing Up

---

If your data is not sensitive store it in `NSUserDefaults`, otherwise *and if this can affect your income* store it somewhere else. If it's sensitive but you don't care if your user lose the counter, save it in a local DB (**CoreData**, **Realm**, etc)

Best time (as of my consideration) for storing new data will be when an intention of closure (*included **suspended state** and **incoming calls***) is notified to your app.

You can save this data in many ways, one that give you some space for maneuvering is saving just **last visit** and date of **first visit of the row** and then do the maths. Of course, updating as needed and explained before.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps me so much:)

Answer (score 2):

```
private extension Sequence where Element == Date {
    
    var streaks: Int {
        let oneDayInSeconds: Double = 60*60*24
        let days = self.compactMap { Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: $0) }
        let uniq = Set(days).sorted(by: >)
        
        var count = 0
        guard var lastStreak = Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, of: Date()) else { return count }
        
        for date in uniq {
            guard date > lastStreak.advanced(by: -oneDayInSeconds - 1) else { break }
            count += 1
            lastStreak = date
        }
        
        return count
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Simply save the last date in your `UserDefault` or `CoreData`, then on the next date, use `timeIntervalSinceDate` to get the timeInterval, divide to 3600, if that value is more than 24, reset the number

Comment: This is not supposed to be in UserDefaults

Comment: Can u explain why?

Comment: @tj3n you should probably save a `currentNumberOfDaysUsed` as well right? Just to know _how many_ days in a row the user has used the app (and reset that when you reset `timeIntervalSinceDate` of course :))

Comment: That's of course? I dont mention because its obvious, also have to override new date over the last date after the counting happen. Just want to know why the last date not suppose to be in UserDefault

Comment: Take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults in the userdefaults only things like currency and language should be stored, as of it is really easy to change data in the plist (where the data from user defaults is stored) https://www.andyibanez.com/nsuserdefaults-not-for-sensitive-data/

Comment: @J.Doe Since it is a small amount of Data, it is fine to use `UserDefaults`. This is designed specifically for storing small amounts of Data

Comment: However, this is not working if the user opens the app one day at 8 am and the other day at 9 pm

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder as Apple says: it it used for storing defaults data, not sensitive data like I think OP means. It does not matter if it is small or big data, there should not be secured data in UserDefaults

Comment: @J.Doe The last time an user opens the app is NOT sensitive data! Sensitive data is   a password, for example, because it is not securely stored in UD

Comment: @J.Doe You are not understand, the key to the answer is flexible, I dont say the OP MUST use UD or CoreData, is their choice, im just simply point them to what they should do to achieve the goal, sensitive or not, you and I both don't know, so better just leave it to the OP choices and his requirement

Answer (score 0):

I didn't checked but this idea will work, simply store current date (DD-MM-YYYY) into Array or list & save it using any [Data Persistence Options](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-data-persistence-and-sandboxing-on-ios--cms-25505). Before adding date (Whenever launching app - you can use didFinishLauchingOptions) into list check whether it had already or not.To showing continuous days use the array count of saved list.

To reset Zero just check last date is Available or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation for keeping track of a login streak and if that streak was rewarded yet:

```
class func checkForStreak() -> Int {
        
        let lastLogin = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lastLogin")
                
        guard let lastLogin = lastLogin else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "loginStreak")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(Date().toString(), forKey: "lastLogin")
            return 1
        }
        
        let format = DateFormatter()
        format.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
        
        guard let lastLoginDate = format.date(from: lastLogin) else {
            return 0
        }
                
        guard let modifiedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: lastLoginDate) else {return 0}
        
        if lastLoginDate.isToday {
            //login on same day
            return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "loginStreak")

        } else if modifiedDate.isToday {
            //streak is extended
            var streak = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "loginStreak")
            streak += 1
            UserDefaults.standard.set(streak, forKey: "loginStreak")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "streakRewarded")
            return streak
        } else {
            //streak is broken
            UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "loginStreak")
            return 1
        }
    }
```

you'll want to set:

```
 UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "streakRewarded")
```

after rewarding the streak. I call this function in my `viewDidLoad` of the root view controller.

Answer (score -1):

```
func streakCount() {
    
    if USERDEFAULTS.value(forKey: "lastLogin") == nil{
        USERDEFAULTS.set(1, forKey: "loginStreak")
        USERDEFAULTS.set(Date().toString(), forKey: "lastLogin")
        return
    }
    
    let lastLogin = USERDEFAULTS.value(forKey: "lastLogin") as! String

    let format = DateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

    guard let lastLoginDate = format.date(from: lastLogin) else {
        return
    }
    
    guard let modifiedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: lastLoginDate) else {
        return
    }
    
   if modifiedDate.isToday {
       //streak is extended
        var streak = USERDEFAULTS.integer(forKey: "loginStreak")
        streak += 1
        USERDEFAULTS.set(streak, forKey: "loginStreak")
        USERDEFAULTS.set(Date().toString(), forKey: "lastLogin")
    } else {
       //streak is broken
        let streak = USERDEFAULTS.integer(forKey: "loginStreak")

        if USERDEFAULTS.value(forKey: "longestStreak") != nil{
            let longestStreak = USERDEFAULTS.integer(forKey: "longestStreak")
            let streak = USERDEFAULTS.integer(forKey: "loginStreak")
            if streak > longestStreak{
                USERDEFAULTS.set(streak, forKey: "longestStreak")
            }
        }
        else{
            USERDEFAULTS.set(streak, forKey: "longestStreak")
        }
        USERDEFAULTS.set(0, forKey: "loginStreak")
   }
}
```